# Adding jcenter() in rootlevel repositories breaks my build

Tags: docker, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a project with a Gradle buildscript and I added the `bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin` to create and push image on new builds.

However I cant use the plugin if I don't specify `jcenter()` in root level repositories, but that breaks my build, so im kinda lost.

If I add the root level `jcenter()` it fails the build with:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
>
> Could not find com.sleepycat:je:7.0.6. Searched in the following locations:
>
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.jar
> - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.pom
> - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.jar
> - https://nexus.company.com/content/groups/public/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.pom
> - https://nexus.company.com/content/groups/public/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.jar
>
> Required by: project : > org.jpos:jpos:2.1.1

However if I don't add it i get this:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':dockerJava'.
>
> Could not find com.aries:docker-java-shaded:3.1.0-rc-3. Searched in the following locations:
>
> - https://nexus.company.com/content/groups/public/com/aries/docker-java-shaded/3.1.0-rc-3/docker-java-shaded-3.1.0-rc-3.pom
> - https://nexus.company.com/content/groups/public/com/aries/docker-java-shaded/3.1.0-rc-3/docker-java-shaded-3.1.0-rc-3-cglib.jar
>
> Required by: project :

Should I perhaps build Java shaded and include in our local Maven repo?

Here is the script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = 'https://nexus.company.com/content/repositories/snapshots/'
            credentials {
                username 'na'
                password 'na'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.company.gradle', name: 'cpmgradle', version: '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.4.4'
    }
}

// ADDING THIS BREAKS MY BUILD BUT IS NECESSARY FOR DOCKER PLUGIN TO WORK
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'com.company.gradle.java'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'

projectinfo {
    group = 'com.company.mesb'
    artifact = 'MESB'
    version = '1.29.DEV-SNAPSHOT'
    description = 'MESB'
    packaging = 'jar'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jpos:jpos:2.1.1'
    compile 'org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6'
    compile 'org.json:json:20140107'
    compile 'com.company.javasdk:JavaSDK:1.1.JDOM2-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.company.javasdk:Base64:1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:2.0.3'
    compile 'org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:2.0.3'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.10'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.54'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.54'

    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

    compile 'com.ibm:mq:5.3.07'
    compile 'com.ibm:mq.pcf:5.3.07'
    compile 'com.ibm:mq.jmqi:5.3.07'
    compile 'com.ibm:mq.headers:5.3.07'
    compile 'com.ibm:mq.commonservices:5.3.07'
    compile 'com.ibm:connector:1.0.0'

    runtime 'jaxen:jaxen:1.1.6'
    runtime 'xalan:xalan:2.7.2'
    runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:8.0-311.jdbc3'
    runtime 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
}

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
    options.fork = true
    options.compilerArgs << '-XDignore.symbol.file'
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
}

task libs(type: Copy) {
    description = "Copies dependencies to the 'lib' directory of the deployment."
    def libsDir = new File("$buildDir", 'libs')
    libsDir.mkdirs()
    def dockerDir = new File("$buildDir", 'docker')
    dockerDir.mkdirs()
    from project.configurations.runtime
    into libsDir
}

task bundleZip(type: Zip) {
    from projectDir

    include 'xsl/**'
    include 'conf/**'
    include 'js/**'
    include 'test/**'
    include 'mesb.sh'

    from(tasks.libs.outputs) {
        include 'MESB*'
    }

    into project.projectinfo.version
}

tasks.bundleZip.dependsOn jar
tasks.bundleZip.dependsOn libs

def dockerUsername = project.properties['dockerUsername'] ?: ""
def dockerPassword = project.properties['dockerPassword'] ?: ""
docker {
    registryCredentials {
        username = dockerUsername
        password = dockerPassword
    }
}

task buildImage(type: com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerBuildImage) {
    doFirst {
        copy {
            from "${buildDir}/libs/MESB-${projectinfo.version}.jar"
            into "${buildDir}/docker"
            rename { String fileName ->
                fileName.replace("-${projectinfo.version}", "")
            }
        }
        copy {
            from "docker/jdk/Dockerfile"
            into "${buildDir}/docker"
        }
        copy {
            from "xsl"
            into "${buildDir}/docker/xsl"
        }
        copy {
            from "conf"
            into "${buildDir}/docker/conf"
        }
        copy {
            from "test"
            into "${buildDir}/docker/test"
        }
        copy {
            from "${buildDir}/libs"
            into "${buildDir}/docker/libs"
        }
    }
    inputDir = project.file("${buildDir}/docker")
    tag = "company/mesb:${projectinfo.version}"
}
tasks.buildImage.dependsOn build

task pushImage(type: com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerPushImage) {
    imageName = "company/mesb"
    tag = "${projectinfo.version}"
}
tasks.pushImage.dependsOn buildImage

artifacts {
    archives bundleZip
}

/* Remove the default JAR file from the uploaded artifacts */
configurations.archives.artifacts.with { archives ->
    def jarArtifact
    archives.each {
        if (it.file =~ 'jar') {
            jarArtifact = it
        }
    }
    remove(jarArtifact)
}

jar {
    dependsOn configurations.runtime
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'main.MESB'
    }
}

tasks.build.dependsOn libs

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently moving root repository definitions benieth the apply plugins section solved this.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'com.company.gradle.java'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'


repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Order matters in gradle scripts. Be sure to check documentation on specific rules.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether you have solved your issue but either way...

I encountered a similar issue regarding:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':dockerJava'.
>
> Could not find com.aries:docker-java-shaded:3.1.0-rc-3.

We solved it by adding the following

```
repositories {
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}
```